# How to style rc-slider using css modules

Tags: reactjs, npm, slider, rc-slider

I have issue with rc-slider
I can't style it using css modules

```
    return (
        <div className={styles.sliderWrapper}>
            <Slider
                className={styles.mySlider}
                range
```

```
.mySlider .rc-slider-track {
    background-color: green !important;
}
```

Can't figure out why this css doesn't affect slider. Styles for outer div works btw

When I try to style with Slider props or with basic .css file and class - it works, but when I use module - it doesn't